# IOS cannot find true format to parse date

Tags: ios, iphone, mongodb, datetime, datetime-format

I have a problem on parsing a date in IOS. Here is the date I got:

> 2013-12-22T20:30:58.020Z

and I cannot parse this date with the following code block:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
entity.updatedAt = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

What is wrong with this formatting?

[EDIT]

When I changed my hour format to HH, it worked in simulator. However hh works fine while debugging in device. Do you have any opinions about this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `hh`, which is the 12-hour clock - but you've provided a value of 20. You want `HH`, which is the 24-hour clock:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

Comment: It works fine with hh in iphone device, however simulator was causing the problem. When I convert it to HH as you said, it also worked in the simulator too. Maybe there is something inconsistent between device and simulator. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Now I don't know much about simulators, but could it be the simulator using system time instead of the device's time?

Comment: @ZaferFatihKoyuncu: Were you using the device during the morning by any chance? Note that it *would* work with values of 01-12...

Comment: It has just happened and time is 1:30 pm at GMT +2. I checked it in both simulator and iPhone. Additionally, my iphone shows the time as 13:30 and the system time (where the simulator runs) is 1:30 pm.

Comment: But what value were you *parsing*? (Sorry, my "during the morning" was probably a red herring - it's what you're parsing that's important, of course.) Either way, you really definitely want HH rather than hh...

Answer (score 0):

RFC Date Time

```
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
    [rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```